# Penalty paid on tax return do i need to amend/modify any changes online

Tags: india, amended-tax-return

I filled my last year's return only and I got penalty for some amount.
I paid that penalty amount but wondering do I need to amend/modify any changes online in my last year's tax return or anything else?

Comment: Forgot to mention it's for Indian tax return

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to amend/modify any changes online in my last year's tax return or anything else?

Yes you need to file an revised tax return for the said year. If you have filed the Original Returns online, then while filing the revised return, there is a drop down, instead of Original; select Revised. If you have paid penalty in response to notice, there is a second drop down you need to select under which section you are filing the revision. You would then need to add the payment details in the tax paid section and submit the revised return.

Note: The revised return should be complete in all sense; i.e. the section of total income, TDS and all other details filed earlier should stay as is and you should add more info to this.